# Is it a true main effect if it is significant only when interaction is included?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation

There is a question [What if interaction wipes out my direct effects in regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5450/what-if-interaction-wipes-out-my-direct-effects-in-regression). An answer was given that the true main effects are in the model without the interaction.

I have the opposite situation. Main effects are not significant in step 1. A main effect is significant in step 2 after adding the interaction, but the interaction is not significant.
Can I rightfully assume this is not a true main effect?

```
DV: guilt
Step 1: Moral conviction (MC) + Speaking out (SO) 
Step 2: MC + SO + MCxSO
```

Comment: "Can I rightfully assume this is not a true main effect?"
Yes.

Comment: The difference between significance and non-significance is not necessarily significant. Are you confusing small changes in p-values across the .05 border with practical importance? or has he size of the main effect changed in a theoretically meaningful way?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "true main effect" and it is, I think, not useful to get hung up on that; instead, present both models (with the coefficients) and describe what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. In this case the p-values across the border go from .090 to .047. The "what to report" becomes an issue because I have over 100 regressions (my dissertation chair had me run all these extra analyses) to report and I'm trying to summarize results appropriately.

Comment: Possible responses for your chair:  1. Should the concepts of parsimony or penalization play any role in this work?  2. At what point would I need to start accounting for the multiple comparison problem?  3. Why stop at about 100?

Comment: @JakeWestfall: Could you flesh that out as an answer?