Does a significant interaction & effect imply an effect in both groups?
I'm fitting an interaction model for two treatment groups: water and saline. Participants of the study, at different ages $X$, begin the treatment and $Y$ is measured.
I fit an interaction model
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot Age + \beta_2 \cdot Saline + \beta_3 \cdot Age \cdot Saline$$
Where $\beta_1$ and $\beta_3$ are significant. This would imply that there is an age effect in the baseline group - water treatment - and that the saline effect of the saline group is different.
But, does this mean there is an age effect in both treatment groups, or only water?
When I fit individual models on each treatment group, for the water (baseline) group, there is a significant $Age$ effect with the same $\beta_1$ value as the interaction model. For the saline group, the $Age$ coefficient is $\beta_1 + \beta_3$ from the interaction model, but, it is not significant.
Which do you trust?

Welcome to CV, John.  I believe this is well covered in several threads here, including https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5450 as well as the duplicate (a popular one, with 18 answers so far).

@whuber I don't understand how either of those questions cover this. Would you mind elaborating?

"Age" and "Spline" are called "main effects."  The duplicate concerns the issue of "fitting individual models," as you write, or using the full model.  If your question truly has something to do with "trust," then please explain what you're trying to get at.  It sounds like your question could have something to do with interpreting "significance," with model selection, with including interactions or not, with comparing models, or possibly something else, so clarification would be helpful.

I would keep the question open. The OP is just having trouble interpreting coefficients when there are interaction terms. This is something many people struggle with and sometimes more general answers may not help.

I'm trying to understand if there is a statistically significant age effect in both the water and saline groups, or just the water group. I do not understand the posts you've linked.
"does this mean there is an age effect in both treatment groups, or only water?"
@GrahamWright if you could provide even two sentences of help that'd be amazing, I've spent 8hr+ trying to understand this.

Best I can do in a comment: If B3 is positive and sig that means that age has a significantly greater effect for the saline group than for the water group.  But in a model limited to the saline group, the beta for age tells you if that effect is significantly different from zero. Different things. If they open the question back up I can give a better answer

@Graham If your interpretation is correct, then we can find many answers already here on CV.  We don't need yet one more thread about that, unless it formulates a distinctly new problem.

I'm just trying to help out a poster who may not have the math background to understand some of those other answers, which are often very technical.  Sometimes people have questions about their particular model, and don't have enough expertise to know how more general or technical answers apply to their particular situation. I think those people deserve help too and I am willing to provide it to them, if I am allowed to do so.
